# How to find activity log file in android smartphone without aLogcat app?

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity, unlock, activitylog

Currently I have a Xiamoi Mi A1 Andorid version 7.1.2.
I want find my mobile activity log file like:

```
2018-10-10 10:02:08 unlock screen
2018-10-10 10:02:20 launch whatsapp
```

I want to find the past logs (i.e. a week ago)

Comment: they are gone. The log buffer is only a few lines long and new logs are constantly added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://myactivity.google.com/ from you cellphone you can recover most important activity. Once on your mobile navigator, you can download the content to a file.